# $\tan^2x - \sec^2x$ express in terms of sin/cos

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to express this problem in terms of sin/cos and simplify. I couldn't figure out where to go, I tried as best I could. I know the answer is -1 but I am more interested to know how to do this problem.

$$
\tan^2x - \sec^2x
$$

$$
(\sin x / \cos x)^2 - (x / \cos x)^2
$$

Comment: The problem is that $\sec(x)=\dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}\neq\dfrac{x}{\cos(x)}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\tan^2x-\sec^2x=\frac{\sin^2x-1}{\cos^2x}=\frac{-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}=-1.$$

Comment: where did the sin^2x go

Comment: $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\tan^2x - \sec^2x
$$
since : $\sec ^2x=1+\tan ^2 x$

so
$$\tan^2x - (1+\tan ^2x)\implies -1$$